# c# Can I apply a method to an IQueryable to convert it to a list?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return a list of `Obj1` types but I first need to pull these using an IQueryable LINQ statement which gives me a list of `Obj2` types, and have a method that converts them to the required type which I apply by using a `foreach` loop

```
public List<Obj1> GetObj1List(int id)
{
    List<Obj2> obj2List = Select(x => x.ObjTable.Where(a => a.Id == id)).ToList();
    List<Obj1> obj1List = new List<Obj1>();

    foreach(Obj2 o in obj2List)
    {
        obj1List.Add(MapObject2ToObject1(o, OtherMethod));
    }
    return obj1List;
}
```

Is there any way I can wrap my `Select` statement to apply the `MapObject2ToObject1` method to the results without having the `foreach` line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be quite easy.

```
public List<Obj1> GetObj1List(int id)
{
    var obj1List = Select(x => x.ObjTable.Where(a => a.Id == id))
        .Select(o => MapObject2ToObject1(o, OtherMethod))
        .ToList();
    return obj1List;
}
```

*Updated with updated method signature for `MapObject2ToObject1`*

Comment: Makes sense but I think I need to supply an argument to MapObject2ToObject1, getting an ArgumentNullException

Comment: @jamheadart you *are* supplying an argument. That call is equivalent to `o=>MapObject2ToObject1(o)`. You didn't post your custom `Select() or `MapObject2ToObject1` code though. If that `Select` produces nulls and `MapObject2ToObject1` doesn't check for nulls, you'll get an NRE

Comment: Sorry, I've looked at my non-minified example and the Map object has a 2nd argument. I've updated my question to include this 2nd method

Comment: @jamheadart the change is trivial - just update `Select` to use the same signature. You should update the question and include all the relevant information though. Perhaps all you need is to get rid of your custom `Select` and just let LINQ work

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You want `AsEnumerable` to effectively use LINQ to Objects for the last mapping part:

```
public List<Obj1> GetObj1List(int id) =>
    Select(x => x.ObjTable.Where(a => a.Id == id)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(MapObject2ToObject1)
    .ToList();
```

(I'm assuming that `Select` is a method in the current class that returns an `IQueryable<Object2>`, given your sample. I'm also assuming you're using C# 6 or higher, so you can use an expression-bodied method like this. If not, put it all in braces and add a return statement.)